# Bad Operand types - First type - java.util.Random, Second type - int

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program where a slot machine takes a random `int`, process it with some `if` statements for a range of numbers, and returning an amount of cash based on what range of numbers the random integer fits into.

The problem derives from the `if` statement, `if(s >= 0 && s < 6 )`, where I am comparing a random object with an `int`.

```
/* This method determines the amount of pay off when there is a winner
 * @ return the amount of payoff
 */
private int getPayOff()
{
    Random s = new Random();
    s.nextInt(11);

    Random rr = new Random();
    rr.nextInt(10 + 1);
    Random rrr = new Random();
    rrr.nextInt(90 + 11);
    if(s >= 0 && s < 6 )
        return rr;
    else if(s >= 6 && s < 9)
        return rrr;
    return 10000;

}
```

Comment: No. You aren't storing the random `int`s anywhere. And you can't return a `Random` when you specify returning an `int`. Why do you have **three** randoms?

Comment: I have 3 randoms, the first is to get a number between 1 and 10, the second is to get a value between 1 and 10 for a payout, and the third is to return a payout between 11 and 101 dollars also, I have declared it at the beginning statement, let me fix that format error

Comment: Why on earth are you creating three `Random` objects? The first one can be used to generate all the random numbers you want.

Comment: really? within the different ranges?, ah could just change the value after the if statements...

Comment: there, fix the format error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to generate two values in the range<sup>1</sup> 1 to 10 and one in the range 11 to 100. You only need one `Random` (a generator for random values), and then you can use it to generate three random values (actually, two random values depending on the code path). Also, you can simplify your `if` chain to remove impossible conditions. Something like,

```
private final Random rand = new Random(); // <-- one.
private int getPayOff() {
    int s = 1 + rand.nextInt(10); // <-- [1,10]
    if (s < 6) {
        return 1 + rand.nextInt(10); // <-- [1,10]
    } else if (s < 9) {
        return 11 + rand.nextInt(90); // <-- [11,100]
    }
    return 10000;
}
```

<sup>1<sub>We add one because [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) *returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*.</sub></sup>

Comment: alright, but how does this not run into a bad operand type, and my code does, and thanks for your time